# Spring Security Is there a way to redirect from an API call without a path?

Tags: redirect, spring-security

I'm building an API in Spring Boot that requires an OAuth client authentication for all significant endpoints.

If someone calls just the URL (without path), we'd like to redirect to the corporate website from the app (keep all business logic in the app) instead of displaying a not authorized page.

I haven't found a way yet to allow an empty string for antMatchers, and the docs imply an empty string is not legal so it's ignored. Anyone have any ideas?

```
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)
      throws Exception {
    //J-
      http
        .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers(
                  HttpMethod.GET,
                  "/v1/admin/livenessHeartbeat",
                  "/v1/admin/readinessHeartbeat",
                  "/v2/api-docs",
                  "/swagger-resources/**",
                  "/swagger-ui.html**",
                  "/webjars/**",
                  "favicon.ico",
                  "/") // No path just base URL which will redirect
              .permitAll()
          .antMatchers("/v1/*").hasRole(ACCESS_ROLE)
          .and()
        .oauth2ResourceServer()
          .accessDeniedHandler(new BearerTokenAccessDeniedHandler())
          .jwt()  
          .jwkSetUri(AUTH_PROVIDER.getMetadata()
            .toCompletableFuture()
            .get()
            .getJWKSetURI().toString())
          .jwtAuthenticationConverter(new SSOAuthExtractor(AUTH_PROVIDER));
```

Comment: Why do you need an empty `String`? What is the URL that you want to redirect? Tthis `"/") // No path just base URL which will redirect` should work.

Comment: It doesn't - "/" still requires authorization

Comment: What URL do you call? Show your full URL.

Comment: The intention of the "/" in the antMatchers is to intercept something like myapidomain.com (no path) where a RedirectController redirects to another URL. That all works fine, except that I have to be authenticated. Spring Boot treats both "" and "/" as invalid so it ignores the antMatcher entry. I'm just wondering if someone else has had this use case and knows a way around authentication for the root URL.

Comment: I may have something else going on - you're right, per the docs, "/" should work.

Comment: What is your context path?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid developer trick #3845 - I was pointing to the wrong environment testing in Postman. Yes, "/" actually works. Thanks for your feedback, dur.

`#FirstDumbThingIveEverDone` Not.